# How do I add background color to unselected tabs in flutter tabbar?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface

I'm making an app with a page with multiple tabs. I want it to look like this:
[image: this]

I want the unselected tabs to have a white background with black font. I have managed to bring it up to this:

[image: current progress]

But I can't find an option to change the background color of unselected tabs. I have changed the text color of unselected tabs to black using the `unselectedLabelColor` property. I tried wrapping the tabbar widget in a container and coloring it but it just filled the entire area around it instead of just the tabs. Any idea on how I can get this without using any external packages?

Comment: Share some code

Comment: does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57543297/12838877

Answer (score 0):

Set Scaffold `backgroundColor` something like `backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,` and use TabController

```dart
class _TabBarDemoState extends State<TabBarDemo>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController controller = TabController(length: 10, vsync: this)
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
```

and

```dart
TabBar(
    isScrollable: true,
    controller: controller,
    tabs: List.generate(
      10,
      (index) => AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        width: 34,//do as you like
        height: 34,//do as you like
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          color: controller.index == index
              ? Colors.deepPurple
              : Colors.white,
          shape: CircleBorder(),
        ),
        child: Text(
          "$index",
          style: controller.index == index
              ? TextStyle()
              : TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    )),
```